# Attempting to build a loop to change one str out of 3 strs in python

Tags: python

My goal is to create 3 lists.

The 1st one is the input: choose 3 from ABCD to create AAA, ABC...etc
The 2nd one is the output: change the middle letter of each input and create a new list. eg: for AAA -> ABA,ACA,ADA. So 3 times the length of the input. 
The third one is the Change: I want to name each change as c_i, for example, AAA->ABA is C1.

For Input,

```
>>> lis = ["A","B","C","D"]
>>> import itertools as it
>>> inp = list(it.product(lis, repeat = 3))
>>> print(inp)
[('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ... ('D', 'D', 'C'), ('D', 'D', 'D')]
>>> len(inp)
64
```

But I am stuck on how to create the output list. Any idea is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant 'product' as in my code.

Comment: `input` is a reserved key word. You should change the name of that variable.

Comment: You are right, thx

Comment: Yes. I am more wondering about how to make list 2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
import itertools

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

lst_input = list(itertools.product(lst, repeat=3))
lst_output = [(tup[0], x, tup[2]) for tup in lst_input for x in lst if tup[1] is not x]
lst_change = [f'C{i}' for i in range(1, len(lst_output) + 1)]

print(len(lst_input), len(lst_output), len(lst_change))
print(lst_input[:5])
print(lst_output[:5])
print(lst_change[:5])

# 64 192 192
# [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'A')]
# [('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'D', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'B')]
# ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5']
```

For each tuple in `lst_input`, the middle item is replaced by all the candidate characters, but the replacement is thrown out if that replacement character is the same as the original character (`if tup[1] is not x`).

Comment: Thank you! This is a very efficient way

Comment: What should I do if I want to replicate each one in lst_input three times to make it like ('A','A','A'),('A','A','A'),('A','A','A'),('A','A','B')...etc?  I tried: lst_input1 = []    for j in range(0,64):
 lst_input1 = append[lst_input[j:j+1]*3], but not working. What should I change to make it? thx

Comment: @Geinkehdsk There might be more efficient method, but try `lst_input1 = [x for x in lst_input for _ in range(3)]`.